# Image isn't displaying full width/height within div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-images

I would like for my row of images to look like the following image (with the margins still in place), but to also have the image showing 100% of it's width. It appears to be cutting out some of the images.

[image: Desktop View]

I would also like for it to show the whole height and width of the image while in mobile view. This is how it looks in mobile view:

[image: Mobile View]

```css
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF HEADSTONE-CATEGORY-SECTION CONTENT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

.headstone-category-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
} /* Sets headstone category divs to take up 100% of the available width within its container */

.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
} /* Sets the way the headstone category divs are displayed (horizontally) 
and allows for them to wrap round each other when screen adjusting */

.grid-item2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.wrapping-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: currentColor;
} /* Allows the user to be able to click anywhere within the headstone category div to access the href link */

.grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  position: relative;border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} /* Adds styling, sets sizing and sets transition speed of the headstone category div */

.grid-item-container2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-image-top2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  max-height: 575px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
} /* Sets sizing and positioning of the images within the headstone category divs */ 

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn43.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the lawn memorials */

.grid-image-top2.churchyard-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn13.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the churchyard memorials */

.grid-image-top2.children-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn27.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the children memorials */

.grid-image-top2.heart-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn42.jpg"); 
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the heart memorials */

.grid-image-top2.books-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn13.jpg"); 
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the books, scrolls and vases */

.grid-item-content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
} /* Adds padding to the text within the headstone category divs */

.grid-item2:hover .grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 1.5% 1.5%;
  margin: -1.5% -1.5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
} /* Adds the padding for when users hover over the headstone category div. Also adds gradient to the small extra space added within the padding */

  /* 83em = 1327px*/
@media(max-width: 1327px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 4 */
}

@media(max-width: 1073px) {
   .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 3 */
}

/* 48em = 768px*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 2 */
}

/* 36em = 577px*/
@media(max-width: 577px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  } /* Adds bottom margin to the headstone category divs */
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF HEADSTONE-CATEGORY-SECTION CONTENT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
```

```html
<section id="headstone-category-section" class="headstone-category-section"> <!-- Start of section -->
  <div class="headstone-category-container"> <!-- Start of div -->
  <h1>Most Popular Headstones:</h1>
  <div class="grid-row"> <!-- Start of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->   
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <span class="centered project-image-bg rex-ray-image"></span>
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
            
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
          <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <span class="centered project-image-bg sputnik-image"></span>
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
              
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div --> 
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 children-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg edgex-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 heart-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg openswitch-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 books-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg scaleio-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      
  </div> <!-- End of heastone-category-container div -->
</section> <!-- This section displays the headstone-category-section -->
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some demo images to your provided code? It displays an empty box at the moment, a little hard to debug

Comment: I've added some in for you. Hope this helps

Comment: Some appear fine depending on the size of the images (images are provided by two different headstone suppliers so they may vary). There is just some in particular that just don't show the whole image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is `background-size: cover;`. If you set it to `contain` it should not crop the image when resizing the browser. Note that I have also added `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. Now the borders are a little odd but that is a different problem, I suggest you to put white background and grey border to achieve your original implementation.

```css
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF HEADSTONE-CATEGORY-SECTION CONTENT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

.headstone-category-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
} /* Sets headstone category divs to take up 100% of the available width within its container */

.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
} /* Sets the way the headstone category divs are displayed (horizontally) 
and allows for them to wrap round each other when screen adjusting */

.grid-item2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.wrapping-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: currentColor;
} /* Allows the user to be able to click anywhere within the headstone category div to access the href link */

.grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  position: relative;border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} /* Adds styling, sets sizing and sets transition speed of the headstone category div */

.grid-item-container2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-image-top2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  max-height: 575px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
} /* Sets sizing and positioning of the images within the headstone category divs */ 

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn43.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the lawn memorials */

.grid-image-top2.churchyard-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn13.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the churchyard memorials */

.grid-image-top2.children-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn27.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the children memorials */

.grid-image-top2.heart-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn42.jpg"); 
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the heart memorials */

.grid-image-top2.books-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn13.jpg"); 
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the books, scrolls and vases */

.grid-item-content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
} /* Adds padding to the text within the headstone category divs */

.grid-item2:hover .grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 1.5% 1.5%;
  margin: -1.5% -1.5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
} /* Adds the padding for when users hover over the headstone category div. Also adds gradient to the small extra space added within the padding */

  /* 83em = 1327px*/
@media(max-width: 1327px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 4 */
}

@media(max-width: 1073px) {
   .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 3 */
}

/* 48em = 768px*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  } /* Sets the headstone category divs to display in a row of 2 */
}

/* 36em = 577px*/
@media(max-width: 577px) {
  .grid-item2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  } /* Adds bottom margin to the headstone category divs */
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF HEADSTONE-CATEGORY-SECTION CONTENT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
```

```html
<section id="headstone-category-section" class="headstone-category-section"> <!-- Start of section -->
  <div class="headstone-category-container"> <!-- Start of div -->
  <h1>Most Popular Headstones:</h1>
  <div class="grid-row"> <!-- Start of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->   
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <span class="centered project-image-bg rex-ray-image"></span>
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
            
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
          <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <span class="centered project-image-bg sputnik-image"></span>
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
              
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div --> 
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 children-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg edgex-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 heart-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg openswitch-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 books-memorials"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg scaleio-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      
  </div> <!-- End of heastone-category-container div -->
</section> <!-- This section displays the headstone-category-section -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm noticing the error with the border but I'm sure I'll be able to try and get a solution. Thanks again